# How may integers should I allow in my container class?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory-management, integer

I don't want the class to cause a crash due to too many values. I realize that it would take 268,435,456 integers (if I did my math correctly) to take up one gigabyte (which is pretty extreme). This value is merely an eighth of a *signed* integer's maximum value (which is what I am currently using for the length. Should I put a cap on this? If so, what would be a reasonable number? Would an unsigned short be a reasonable length? Have you ever needed an array with more than 65,536 values?

Comment: Why impose an artificial upper bound anyway? If in doubt, do as the STL containers do (which don't impose a limit, except through the maximum value which can be represented in the `size_type` type - which is large enough for most purposes).

Comment: "Have you ever needed an array with more than 65,536 values" of course. I have 1310720 pixels on my screen.

Comment: @ybungalobill Of course, I didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Placing arbitrary limits on your classes is considered bad practice.

You should allow the user to put as many items as they want into your container; if they try to put too many in, it's their job to deal with the `std::bad_alloc` exception that will be thrown.

Comment: You're welcome for the extra privileges. Hehe. Very short and concise. Thanks.

Comment: +1. For a class, this is absolutely true. For an entire program, maybe not as much. It's easier to test a business or user required upper limit, and corresponding error handling code, than it is to test `std::bad_alloc`

Answer (score 1):

> Have you ever needed an array with more than 65,536 values?

I have tons of files on my hard drive that are way bigger than this (mp3s come to mind, as well as some executables).

Might I want an entire file in memory at one time?  Of course.

**Suggestions for a whole application**

Computers will only get more memory as time goes on, so don't hamstring your application with deeply hard-coded values.

One way to do this is to use variable-sized containers, such as `std::vector` to contain your values.  You can then leave your user input validation code to place the limit.

Generally you should check user input (including input files, values passed in fields, values passed in functions, etc) and put artificial (but reasonably large) caps on these values.  Then leave your internal code free to grow as necessary.  This makes it much easier to test your program, since you have a target "maxed out" value to shoot for.  You can test and confidently say you support those upper limits, and you can test error handling when the user uses values above those limits.

Later on, if you really need/want to, you can do performance profiling/testing to adjust your application's limits to fit within a target memory footprint, or best limit the data to remain performant.

**Suggestions for simple/lower level classes**

Don't add any hard-coded values.  Use variable sized containers, and let your higher level code deal with any hard-limiting.

It is up to the user to use your code correctly, lest they have an exception thrown.  The code in your class also should not try to catch this out of memory exception, since your code almost assuredly can't recover from it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally expected that general purpose containers will not impose arbitrary limits on the client.  If you're concerned about saving memory - thinking your client coder (the user of your container "library" code) will be concerned - then consider giving them the choice by making it a template parameter.  The downside then is that you can end up with multiple types of containers - and template instantiations - for a single value type.  Not a big deal generally.  And more generally, it's no more likely that the client will accidentally push too many items into your container than that they'll accidentally leak memory in a loop somewhere or multiply the size for their heap allocation by some MB_MULTIPLIER twice by accident.  If they're worried, let them write `if (container.size() > 65535) throw "not likely mate";`.  You simply can't fight certain kinds of client misuse and have to let them get it right during dev & testing.

Answer (score -1):

I have used boolean(bool type) arrays with capaity of **20000000**.

As for the max size, clearly you should not try to accommodate more data than that can fit in memory. However, if situation demands handling large quantity of number, you would need to change your program design.